# No signature of method: build

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Build.gardle

```java
Plugins{

Id 'com.android.application'

Id 'kotlin-android'

}

Android {

   ViewBinding{


     enabled=true
}

CompileSdkVersion 31

BuildToolsVersion 30.0.3

defaultConfig{

 applicationid 
com.example.quizapp

MinSdkVersion 21

targetSdkVersion 31

VersionCode 1

VersionName "1.0"

testInstrumentationRunner"Android x.test.runner.AndroidJUnutRunner" }

}

BuildTypes{

release {

MinifyEnabled false

ProguardFiles getDefaultproguardFile(proguard-android-optimize.txt), proguard-rules.pro

}

}

CompileOptions {

SourceCompatability javaversion.Version_1_8

targetcompatibility javaVersion.Version_1_8

}

KotlinOptions{

 JvmTarget = 1.8

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `build.gradle` file seems to not be formatted correctly. Please refer to the following file and make the changes accordingly

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.raywenderlich.android.memories"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  // Kotlin
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

  // Support Libraries
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
  implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

  // Testing Dependencies
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

  // TUTORIAL DEPENDENCIES HERE
  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
  implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.8.0'
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2")
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0'

  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1'
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'

  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

  implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0"
}
```